# stringr package str_extract() with inversion of the regex

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have a string like the following: 
14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27.0

The following regex extracts the last part that ends in a dot and a digit. I want to extract everything but that part and can't seem to find a way to invert the regex (using ^) is not helping:

```
> s <- '14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27.0'
> str_extract(s, '(\\.[0-9]{1})$')
[1] ".0"
```

I instead want the output to be:

```
[1] 14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27
```

To clarify further, I want it to return the string as is, if it does not end in a dot and one single digit.

Following example:

```
> s <- '14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27'
> str_extract(s, someRegex)
[1] "14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27"
> s <- '14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27.1'
> str_extract(s, someRegex)
[1] "14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27"
> s <- '14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27.4'
> str_extract(s, someRegex)
[1] "14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^.*(?=\.\d+$)|^.*
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/iM1jI0/2)

Comment: I can edit the question, but I don't want it to chop off anything that ends in more than one digit after the last '.'

Comment: @user3949008. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be substituting for the last bit,

```
sub("\\.\\d$", '', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_extract(s, ([\w ]+(?:\.|\-)){7})
```

Then you can access the returned string to its lenght-1, and it will give you the required output!

PS: You may have to use escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stringr::str_remove()` for example:

```r
s <- '14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27.0'
stringr::str_remove(s, '(\\.[0-9]{1})$')
#> [1] "14ed0d69fa2.bbd.7f5512.filter-132.21026.55B67C8E27"
```